# Does SharePoint actions such as "GetItem", "GetItems", "Grant access to an Item or folder" , etc uses SharePoint api or Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I have a question if SharePoint actions such as "GetItem", "GetItems", "Grant access to an Item or folder", etc uses SharePoint API or Graph API?

[image: johnjohn123_0-1680472411129.png]

Answer (score 1):

Actions in Power Automate like `GetItem`, `GetItems`, `Grant access to an Item or folder`, etc. use SharePoint API.

It will run using account using which you created your Power Automate.

See more details on SharePoint Connectors:

- [Power Automate - SharePoint Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#actions)

Comment: but based on Microsoft recommendation that SharePoint aPI is considered legacy compared to the newer Graph API , am i correct?

Comment: Yes. that's correct but until they don't provide Graph API for the relevant SharePoint API, we should hope that they will not deprecate those SharePoint API :)

Comment: If this information helped to you then please mark this as answer so that it will be helpful to other in this community